# Why is `'b' in 'b' is 'b'` is True in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run this is python console:

```py
>>> 'b' in 'b' is 'b'
```

I get this result

```
True
```

Similar, when I run this：

```py
>>> 'b' in 'b' == 'b'
```

The answer is still `True`, which greatly made me confused.

The experiments I have done:

```py
>>> 'b' in ('b' is 'b')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

```py
>>> ('b' in 'b') is 'b'
False
```

Can anyone explain how this happened and the priority of python interceptor do the job of `in`, `==`, and `is`?

Comment: look up expression chaining

Comment: `'b' in 'b' is 'b'` expands to `'b' in 'b' and  'b' is 'b'`

Comment: @Chris_Rands Wow thanks, fantastic quick response to my question.

Comment: Also 'b' in 'ba' in 'bac' expands to 'b' in 'ba' and 'ba' in 'bac' and gives True !